# LWC lightning-badge in cell of lightning-datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, lightning-datatable

I am trying to place one or more lightning-badges inside the cells of my lightning-datatable. I've been successful in using icons instead of cells, but I haven't been able to find a solution for badges. Does anyone have any tips for accomplishing this?

Comment: You can extend lightning-datatable to add a custom data type. See the documentation for details.